# DevExpress XtraGrid force filter to display individual values for RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit column

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have added a column with RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit as an editor. Each row for that column can feature one or more entries from a predefined list of categories (let's call them Category1, Category2 and Category3) which are strings and are read from the database.

My problem is that the filter will list options such as: "Category1; Category2" as well as "Category1" or "Category1; Category2; Category3", depending on what it finds in the grid for said column (if one of the rows has all three categories selected that will be considered an individual filter option, instead of breaking down the value into its components).

I would like the filter to only list single values, instead of combinations, but I'm unable to find a solution for that. I have tried using the ShowFilterPopupCheckedListBox event in order to manipulate the filter contents, but now filtering has stopped working for that column altogether.

Here is my code:

```
void gridView_ShowFilterPopupCheckedListBox(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.FilterPopupCheckedListBoxEventArgs e)
{
    List<CheckedListBoxItem> atomicValues = new List<CheckedListBoxItem>();
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "CategoryCollection") { return; }
    for (int i = 0; i < e.CheckedComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckedListBoxItem item = e.CheckedComboBox.Items[i];
        string itemValue = (string)(item.Value as FilterItem).Value;
        string[] atomicItemValues = itemValue.Split(';');
        foreach (string atomicValue in atomicItemValues)
        {
            string trimmedAtomicValue = atomicValue.Trim();
            atomicValues.Add(new CheckedListBoxItem(trimmedAtomicValue));
        }
    }

    List<CheckedListBoxItem> distinctAtomicValues = atomicValues.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(group => group.First()).OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
    e.CheckedComboBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (CheckedListBoxItem atomicItem in distinctAtomicValues)
    {
        e.CheckedComboBox.Items.Add(atomicItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, checked filter dropdown list does not allow to add custom items.

As an alternative solution, you can use the Auto Filter Row for filtering a column by using an in-place CheckedComboBoxEdit:

- Enable GridView.OptionsView.ShowAutoFilterRow property to true.
- Assign in-place CheckedComboBoxEdit to auto filter row cell
- Handle the GridView.CustomRowCellEdit event in the following way:

-

```
private void gridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "YourField" && e.RowHandle == GridControl.AutoFilterRowHandle)
    {
        e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no build-in functions in `GridView`, so you need to create your custom descendant from `GridView` class.

- You need to apply your custom filter criteria, because default `GridView` are applying `equals` operator for checked filter, but you need to use `contains` criteria. For this you need to ovveride `ApplyCheckedColumnFilter` method of `GridView`.
- Also if you want to show currently applied filters in popup, then you need to update `FilterValues` property of `CheckedColumnFilterPopup.RepositoryItemFilterComboBox` object. You can get this object from `FilterPopupCheckedListBoxEventArgs.CheckedComboBox` property by casting it to `CheckedColumnFilterPopup.RepositoryItemFilterComboBox`.

Here is example:

Custom `GridView` descendant:

```
public class CustomGridView : GridView
{
    protected override void ApplyCheckedColumnFilter(GridColumn column, object stringValues, List<object> checkedValues)
    {
        if (column.ColumnEdit is RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit)
        {
            var groupOperator =
                new GroupOperator(
                    GroupOperatorType.Or,
                    from checkedValue in checkedValues
                    where checkedValue != null
                    select
                       new FunctionOperator(
                           FunctionOperatorType.Contains,
                           new OperandProperty(column.FieldName),
                           new OperandValue(checkedValue)));

            ColumnFilterInfo filterInfo;

            switch (groupOperator.Operands.Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    filterInfo = new ColumnFilterInfo();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    filterInfo = new ColumnFilterInfo(groupOperator.Operands[0]);
                    break;
                default:
                    filterInfo = new ColumnFilterInfo(groupOperator);
                    break;
            }

            column.FilterInfo = filterInfo;
        }
        else
            base.ApplyCheckedColumnFilter(column, stringValues, checkedValues);
    }
}
```

`ShowFilterPopupCheckedListBox` event handler method:

```
private void gridView1_ShowFilterPopupCheckedListBox(object sender, FilterPopupCheckedListBoxEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Column.ColumnEdit is RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit)) { return; }

    var distinctAtomicValues =
        (from value in
             (from atomicItemValues in
                  from item in e.CheckedComboBox.Items.OfType<CheckedListBoxItem>()
                  let itemValue = (string)(item.Value as FilterItem).Value
                  where itemValue != null
                  select itemValue.Split(';')
              from atomicValue in atomicItemValues
              let trimmedAtomicValue = atomicValue.Trim()
              orderby trimmedAtomicValue
              select trimmedAtomicValue).Distinct()
         select new CheckedListBoxItem(value)).ToList();

    e.CheckedComboBox.Items.Clear();

    foreach (var atomicItem in distinctAtomicValues)
        e.CheckedComboBox.Items.Add(atomicItem);

    string filterString = e.Column.FilterInfo.FilterString;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterString))
    {
        var filterItem = (CheckedColumnFilterPopup.RepositoryItemFilterComboBox)e.CheckedComboBox;

        filterItem.FilterValues =
            string.Join("\n",
                from item in filterItem.Items.OfType<CheckedListBoxItem>()
                let itemValue = (string)item.Value
                where itemValue != null && filterString.Contains("Contains([" + e.Column.FieldName + "], '" + item.Value + "'")
                select itemValue);
    }
}
```